# QEMU for ARM programs with GDB

Tags: linux, qemu, arm, gdb, assembly

I want to  emulate an ARM processor for running the assembly programs using QEMU in RHEL. I have installed QEMU but I still have problems in running the assembly program. I got the assembly program, memory map and the makefile from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802748/arm-assembly-using-qemu) link. However, if I run the below command,

```
qemu-system-arm -S -s -M versatilepb -daemonize -m 128M -d in_asm,cpu,exec -kernel hello_world.bin ; gdb-multiarch --batch --command=hello_world.gdb
```

I get an error as "hello_world.bin - No such file or directory". I am not sure what is to be done to run the above command. So, I got an ARM image from [this](http://wiki.qemu.org/Testing) link. Instead of hello_world.bin, if I specify the kernel name as "**zImage.Integrator**", I am getting a QEMU console window. However, I am not able to type or do anything in that window. Can someone please let me know how to run an assembly program using QEMU for ARM?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408041/how-to-debug-the-linux-kernel-with-gdb-and-qemu/33203642#33203642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured out what am making wrong. I should actually run the make command which will create my object file and binary file. I got more information on running the command from [this](http://www.bravegnu.org/gnu-eprog/hello-arm.html) link. Now, I have to figure out how to install GDB to interact between the ARM and QEMU.

Comment: I ran using the below commands. `echo "PATH=$PATH:/opt/ARM/bin" >> /home/"$(whoami)"/.bashrc`
`source /home/"$(whoami)"/.bashrc`